# Why is a simple function measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Sorry for the really trivial question.

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ where $Rangef=\{a_1 ,...,a_n\}$ and $A_i =f^{-1}(a_i)$ .

I'm having trouble showing if $f=\sum^n _{i=1} a_i \chi_{A_i} $ is measurable then $A_i\in \cal{A}$

Suppose $f$ is measurable then $f^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal{A}, \forall U \in ??$

[What exactly is the sigma algebra going to be in this case? $\cal{B} (\mathbb{C})?$]

I suspect that if I determine that $\{a_i\}\in ??,\forall i $ then $A_i=f^{-1}(\{a_i\})\in\mathcal{A}, \forall i $ follows.

For the converse I've shown that the product and sum of measurable functions is measurable and so $f$ must too be measurable.

Is there a slick way to show this? I think what really threw a wrench in the works was $\mathbb{C}$ being taken as the codomain...

Comment: If $f$ is measurable, then $f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{A}$ for any open set $U\subset \mathbb{C}$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma-algebra, we may replace "open" in the previous sentence by "closed". In particular, $A_i := f^{-1}(\{a_i\})\in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Fair enough, I understand that since $\{a_i\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ then it must also be closed in $\mathbb{C}$ but how do you show the converse easily? The method I took seems to be tedious

Comment: Can you show that $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{a_i\}$ is open? You need the fact that any two distinct points can be separated by a positive distance.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan
No no I understand how $\{a_i\}$ is closed :)

How do you show that if $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$ then $f$ is measurable?

Comment: If $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$, then $\chi_{A_i}$ is measurable. So $f$ is the linear combination of measurable functions - hence measurable.